# Eclipse IDE does not create Maven Dependencies on save of POM file

Tags: eclipse, maven

When I copy and paste a dependency into my pom.xml file in Eclipse, and then click save, nothing happens.

In the video below, when the pom.xml file is saved, a Maven Dependency folder is created and the appropriate jar file is listed when Maven Dependency folder is expanded:
[Maven Vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNEcpw8LPpo&t=814s)

How do I change Eclipse to mimic the behavior shown?

Comment: Have you run `ALT+F5`?

Comment: Maybe your Eclipse is too old. Automatically updating on saving the POM is the default behavior for quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have Build Automatically checked in Eclipse

[image]

To update your project with Maven Dependencies manually - right click your project in Project Explorer -> Maven -> Update Project
[image]

Comment: Build auto worked, update project ... not so much.

Comment: Update project is useful if you changed the dependency version in your pom file and want to download a newer version.